# Get Current User within WCF Web service using CSOM on Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, csom

The key part here is that the application is running within a **WCF** Web service application, and is being called from a URL. My setup for the WCF service is almost identical to this tutorial - https://jobrocol.wordpress.com/2012/06/03/custom-rest-wcf-service-in-sharepoint-2010/comment-page-1/

I created a small test, just a console application. This code works as intended:

```
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

public static void addNewItemToSPList() {
    string siteUrl = "http://my.domain.com/";
    string subSite = "temp/subsite";
    string spList = "GenericTestList";

    bool returnVal = false;
    try {
        using (ClientContext clientCtx = new ClientContext(siteUrl + subSite)) {
            // Get default credentials
            clientCtx.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

            if (DoesUserHavePermissions(clientCtx, spList, PermissionKind.AddListItems)) {

                SP.List oList = clientCtx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(spList);

                ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
                oListItem["Title"] = "Test";

                oListItem.Update();

                // Add a new list item
                clientCtx.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

public static bool DoesUserHavePermissions(ClientContext ctx, string listname, PermissionKind permmask) {
    try {
        SP.List TargetList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listname);
        ctx.Load(TargetList, T => T.EffectiveBasePermissions);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        return TargetList.EffectiveBasePermissions.Has(permmask);
    } catch {
        return false;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    addNewItemToSPList();
}
```

However, when I try to do something very similar within the WCF application, I get errors. Pretty much just 401 Access Denied errors.

I pretty sure my issue is how I'm getting my `clientCtx.Credentials`, but I've tried a but of ways to get the currently logged in user creds for the SP site but none seem to be working.

Any advice? I can include some of the WCF code but it is pretty much identical to the stand-alone console app proof-of-concept code above.